# how to parse false values in mustache

Tags: templates, mustache

I am new to mustache. Have an object like

```
object = [{
    name: 'A',
    fields: { type: "string" }
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    fields: { type: "boolean", default: false }
  }]
```

I am passing that object to mustache template and I want generated code where default values are also shown.

**Code:**

```
{{#object}}
   var {{name}}: {{#fields}} {{type}} {{^default}} = {{default}} {{/default}}{{/fields}}
{{/object}}
```

But I am not able to get the expected output from above code.

**Expected Output:**

```
var A: string
var B: boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If `default` were the *string* `"false"` it would (almost) work. You've currently got the equivalent to:

```
default = false
if (!default) {
  " = " + default
}
```

… but you need:

```
default = "false"
if (default) {
  " = " + default
}
```

So this would do it for you:

```
object = [{
  name: 'A',
  fields: { type: "string" }
},
{
  name: 'B',
  fields: { type: "boolean", default: "false" }
}]
```

… and change the `{{^default}}` block to `{{#default}}`:

```
{{#object}}
   var {{name}}: {{#fields}} {{type}} {{#default}} = {{default}} {{/default}}{{/fields}}
{{/object}}
```

Comment: I cannot manipulate object like `false` to `"false"`. Also I tried with `{{#default}}` but it is not working. : ' (

Comment: The answer to this, like the answer to most Mustache questions, is "prepare the data". You're not going to be able to generate the code you need if you can't manipulate the data before it gets passed to Mustache.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
object : [
  {
    name: 'A',
    fields: { type: "string" }
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    fields: { type: "boolean", default: "false"}
  }
]
```

with

```
{{#object}}
   var {{name}}: {{#fields}} {{type}} {{#default}} = {{default}} {{/default}}{{^default}}{{/default}}{{/fields}}
{{/object}}
```

if the false cannot change to "false" and you want a result like you show above,you may try:

```
object : [
  {
    name: 'A',
    fields: { type: "string", default: true}
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    fields: { type: "boolean", default: false}
  }
]
```

with

```
{{#object}}
   var {{name}}: {{#fields}} {{type}} {{#default}}{{/default}}{{^default}}= false{{/default}}{{/fields}}
{{/object}}
```

Comment: Same problem : ' (  I cannot manipulate object like adding `default: true`. I am getting object where sometimes `default` key is present with different values like `0`, `true`, `false` etc.

Comment: as i understand, when a key's boolean value is true,mustache will render as this key exists, use {{#key}}...{{/key}}; when key's value is false, use {{^key}}...{{/key}}. i think you have to change your data object to a non boolean value. @SpunkyLive

Comment: Hmm.. That is the problem. I cannot change the data.